Making axes visible in plotly 3D chart
I'm having problems with making axes visible in a plotly 3D chart. I would assume fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black') should do it but it is not having any effects, it looks like I'm missing something.
Additionally, I would like to display arrows for the axes.
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import sys 
from random import randint as rint
import pandas as pd

headers = ("Rank", "GMV", "Inventory", "Categories", "ETRS")
sellers = [(rint(20, 100), rint(500, 10000), rint(10, 200), rint(1, 6), rint(0, 1) == 1) \
           for _ in range(100)]

df = pd.DataFrame(sellers, columns=headers)

fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='Inventory', y='Rank', z='GMV', size='Categories', color='ETRS')
                        
fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black')
fig.show()



Axes for 3d graphs are set in scene. Arrows were added with string annotations with no good results. Please refer to this reference.
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import sys 
from random import randint as rint
import pandas as pd

headers = ("Rank", "GMV", "Inventory", "Categories", "ETRS")
sellers = [(rint(20, 100), rint(500, 10000), rint(10, 200), rint(1, 6), rint(0, 1) == 1) \
           for _ in range(100)]

df = pd.DataFrame(sellers, columns=headers)

fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='Inventory', y='Rank', z='GMV', size='Categories', color='ETRS')
                        
fig.update_layout(
    scene=dict(
        xaxis=dict(showline=True, linewidth=3, linecolor='black'),
        annotations=[
            dict(
                x=0,
                y=100,
                z=0,
                text='>',
                textangle=-45,
                xanchor='left',
                xshift=0,
                # ax=-10,
                # ay=150,
                showarrow=False,
                # arrowcolor='black',
                # arrowsize=1,
                # arrowwidth=2,
                # arrowhead=1
            )
        ]
    ))
fig.update_layout(height=600, margin=dict(t=0))
fig.show()



Thanks for the answer. I would expect the axis lines pass through (0, 0, 0) but it doesn't seem to be the case...

It would be easier if it could be specified on the axis. Also, it may be possible to specify on the graph area, but it may take some trial and error to find the value. You have achieved your first goal.
